# Qt ignoring owner font and using system font

Tags: qt, unicode, fonts

I have:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


  QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QFont f(a.font());
    f.setPointSize(17);
    f.setFamily("Arial AMU");
    a.setFont(f);
    QLineEdit *l = new QLineEdit();
    l->setFont(f);
    l->show();    
    return a.exec();
}
```

I try to change unicode font for Armenian Language. In Windows OS, default font for this language is Sylfaen. But i want to use Arial AMU font, and this font support this language. So, i set new font for my application, all Latin symbols displayed correctly, except Armenian symbols! In this case, qt using the system font!